# .net identityUser datetimeoffset mismatch postgresql

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using dotnet core with postgresql and all of a sudden (i guess there was an update to something) it all stoped working. [image]

This is the entity my user entity is inheriting from. 
Here lockoutend is DateTimeOffset? and in my postgres table:

```
  CREATE TABLE public.users
  (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    accessfailedcount integer NOT NULL,
    concurrencystamp character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    emailconfirmed boolean NOT NULL,
    lockoutenabled boolean NOT NULL,
    lockoutend timestamp with time zone,
    name character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    normalizedemail character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    normalizedusername character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    passwordhash character varying(512) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phonenumber character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phonenumberconfirmed boolean NOT NULL,
    securitystamp character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    twofactorenabled boolean NOT NULL,
    username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    locale integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
   OWNER to notifiedlocal;


CREATE INDEX emailindex
    ON public.users USING btree
    (normalizedemail COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX usernameindex
    ON public.users USING btree
    (normalizedusername COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

This is the error i get when i try to do a simple get from the user table:

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: 'An exception occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]'


"An exception occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 
'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]' but the actual value was of type 
'System.DateTime'."
```

So have i accidentally updated postgres and .net identity so that one of the sides changed? 
This used to work and i haven't changed anything on purpose. 
Is it possible to change the identity entity to use normal datetime instead?

Comment: Same thin in SQL Server v13

Comment: public virtual DateTimeOffset? CreationDate { get; set; }

Comment: [CreationDate]   DATETIME2(0)    NULL,